# Highcharts drill down - x-Axis labels loss on drillup

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts for creating a drilldownchart.
When using a large dataset (~100), the labels on x-Axis of primary chart get lost when you drill up. Is there any work around to it that allows data labels to be retained when return to the primary chart on drill up?

Please refer to example at: http://jsfiddle.net/rofyy9th/2/

```
    $(function () {
        // Create the chart
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total percent market share'
                }

            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                    }
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '',
                pointFormat: ''
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Brands',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{ name: 'Point1', y: 100, drilldown: 'Point1' },
                        { name: 'Point2', y: 101, drilldown: 'Point2' },
                        { name: 'Point3', y: 102, drilldown: 'Point3' },
                        { name: 'Point4', y: 103, drilldown: 'Point4' },
                        { name: 'Point5', y: 104, drilldown: 'Point5' },
                        { name: 'Point6', y: 105, drilldown: 'Point6' },
                        { name: 'Point7', y: 106, drilldown: 'Point7' },
                        { name: 'Point8', y: 107, drilldown: 'Point8' },
                        { name: 'Point9', y: 108, drilldown: 'Point9' },
                        { name: 'Point10', y: 109, drilldown: 'Point10' },
                        { name: 'Point11', y: 110, drilldown: 'Point11' },
                        { name: 'Point12', y: 111, drilldown: 'Point12' },
                        { name: 'Point13', y: 112, drilldown: 'Point13' },
                        { name: 'Point14', y: 113, drilldown: 'Point14' },
                        { name: 'Point15', y: 114, drilldown: 'Point15' },
                        { name: 'Point16', y: 115, drilldown: 'Point16' },
                        { name: 'Point17', y: 116, drilldown: 'Point17' },
                        { name: 'Point18', y: 117, drilldown: 'Point18' },
                        { name: 'Point19', y: 118, drilldown: 'Point19' },
                        { name: 'Point20', y: 119, drilldown: 'Point20' },
                        { name: 'Point21', y: 120, drilldown: 'Point21' },
                        { name: 'Point22', y: 121, drilldown: 'Point22' },
                        { name: 'Point23', y: 122, drilldown: 'Point23' },
                        { name: 'Point24', y: 123, drilldown: 'Point24' },
                        { name: 'Point25', y: 124, drilldown: 'Point25' },
                        { name: 'Point26', y: 125, drilldown: 'Point26' },
                        { name: 'Point27', y: 126, drilldown: 'Point27' },
                        { name: 'Point28', y: 127, drilldown: 'Point28' },
                        { name: 'Point29', y: 128, drilldown: 'Point29' },
                        { name: 'Point30', y: 129, drilldown: 'Point30' },
                        { name: 'Point31', y: 130, drilldown: 'Point31' },
                        { name: 'Point32', y: 131, drilldown: 'Point32' },
                        { name: 'Point33', y: 132, drilldown: 'Point33' },
                        { name: 'Point34', y: 133, drilldown: 'Point34' },
                        { name: 'Point35', y: 134, drilldown: 'Point35' },
                        { name: 'Point36', y: 135, drilldown: 'Point36' },
                        { name: 'Point37', y: 136, drilldown: 'Point37' },
                        { name: 'Point38', y: 137, drilldown: 'Point38' },
                        { name: 'Point39', y: 138, drilldown: 'Point39' },
                        { name: 'Point40', y: 139, drilldown: 'Point40' },
                        { name: 'Point41', y: 140, drilldown: 'Point41' },
                        { name: 'Point42', y: 141, drilldown: 'Point42' },
                        { name: 'Point43', y: 142, drilldown: 'Point43' },
                        { name: 'Point44', y: 143, drilldown: 'Point44' },
                        { name: 'Point45', y: 144, drilldown: 'Point45' },
                        { name: 'Point46', y: 145, drilldown: 'Point46' },
                        { name: 'Point47', y: 146, drilldown: 'Point47' },
                        { name: 'Point48', y: 147, drilldown: 'Point48' },
                        { name: 'Point49', y: 148, drilldown: 'Point49' },
                        { name: 'Point50', y: 149, drilldown: 'Point50' },
                        { name: 'Point51', y: 150, drilldown: 'Point51' },
                        { name: 'Point52', y: 151, drilldown: 'Point52' },
                        { name: 'Point53', y: 152, drilldown: 'Point53' },
                        { name: 'Point54', y: 153, drilldown: 'Point54' },
                        { name: 'Point55', y: 154, drilldown: 'Point55' },
                        { name: 'Point56', y: 155, drilldown: 'Point56' },
                        { name: 'Point57', y: 156, drilldown: 'Point57' },
                        { name: 'Point58', y: 157, drilldown: 'Point58' },
                        { name: 'Point59', y: 158, drilldown: 'Point59' },
                        { name: 'Point60', y: 159, drilldown: 'Point60' },
                        { name: 'Point61', y: 160, drilldown: 'Point61' },
                        { name: 'Point62', y: 161, drilldown: 'Point62' },
                        { name: 'Point63', y: 162, drilldown: 'Point63' },
                        { name: 'Point64', y: 163, drilldown: 'Point64' },
                        { name: 'Point65', y: 164, drilldown: 'Point65' },
                        { name: 'Point66', y: 165, drilldown: 'Point66' },
                        { name: 'Point67', y: 166, drilldown: 'Point67' },
                        { name: 'Point68', y: 167, drilldown: 'Point68' },
                        { name: 'Point69', y: 168, drilldown: 'Point69' },
                        { name: 'Point70', y: 169, drilldown: 'Point70' },
                        { name: 'Point71', y: 170, drilldown: 'Point71' },
                        { name: 'Point72', y: 171, drilldown: 'Point72' },
                        { name: 'Point73', y: 172, drilldown: 'Point73' },
                        { name: 'Point74', y: 173, drilldown: 'Point74' },
                        { name: 'Point75', y: 174, drilldown: 'Point75' },
                        { name: 'Point76', y: 175, drilldown: 'Point76' },
                        { name: 'Point77', y: 176, drilldown: 'Point77' },
                        { name: 'Point78', y: 177, drilldown: 'Point78' },
                        { name: 'Point79', y: 178, drilldown: 'Point79' },
                        { name: 'Point80', y: 179, drilldown: 'Point80' },
                        { name: 'Point81', y: 180, drilldown: 'Point81' },
                        { name: 'Point82', y: 181, drilldown: 'Point82' },
                        { name: 'Point83', y: 182, drilldown: 'Point83' },
                        { name: 'Point84', y: 183, drilldown: 'Point84' },
                        { name: 'Point85', y: 184, drilldown: 'Point85' },
                        { name: 'Point86', y: 185, drilldown: 'Point86' },
                        { name: 'Point87', y: 186, drilldown: 'Point87' },
                        { name: 'Point88', y: 187, drilldown: 'Point88' },
                        { name: 'Point89', y: 188, drilldown: 'Point89' },
                        { name: 'Point90', y: 189, drilldown: 'Point90' },
                        { name: 'Point91', y: 190, drilldown: 'Point91' },
                        { name: 'Point92', y: 191, drilldown: 'Point92' },
                        { name: 'Point93', y: 192, drilldown: 'Point93' },
                        { name: 'Point94', y: 193, drilldown: 'Point94' },
                        { name: 'Point95', y: 194, drilldown: 'Point95' },
                        { name: 'Point96', y: 195, drilldown: 'Point96' },
                        { name: 'Point97', y: 196, drilldown: 'Point97' },
                        { name: 'Point98', y: 197, drilldown: 'Point98' },
                        { name: 'Point99', y: 198, drilldown: 'Point99' },
                        { name: 'Point100', y: 199, drilldown: 'Point100' }

                        ]
            }],
            drilldown: {
                series: [{ name: 'Point1', id: 'Point1', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 5]] },
                            { name: 'Point2', id: 'Point2', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 6]] },
                            { name: 'Point3', id: 'Point3', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 7]] },
                            { name: 'Point4', id: 'Point4', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 8]] },
                            { name: 'Point5', id: 'Point5', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 9]] },
                            { name: 'Point6', id: 'Point6', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 10]] },
                            { name: 'Point7', id: 'Point7', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 11]] },
                            { name: 'Point8', id: 'Point8', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 12]] },
                            { name: 'Point9', id: 'Point9', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 13]] },
                            { name: 'Point10', id: 'Point10', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 14]] },
                            { name: 'Point11', id: 'Point11', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 15]] },
                            { name: 'Point12', id: 'Point12', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 16]] },
                            { name: 'Point13', id: 'Point13', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 17]] },
                            { name: 'Point14', id: 'Point14', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 18]] },
                            { name: 'Point15', id: 'Point15', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 19]] },
                            { name: 'Point16', id: 'Point16', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 20]] },
                            { name: 'Point17', id: 'Point17', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 21]] },
                            { name: 'Point18', id: 'Point18', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 22]] },
                            { name: 'Point19', id: 'Point19', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 23]] },
                            { name: 'Point20', id: 'Point20', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 24]] },
                            { name: 'Point21', id: 'Point21', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 25]] },
                            { name: 'Point22', id: 'Point22', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 26]] },
                            { name: 'Point23', id: 'Point23', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 27]] },
                            { name: 'Point24', id: 'Point24', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 28]] },
                            { name: 'Point25', id: 'Point25', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 29]] },
                            { name: 'Point26', id: 'Point26', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 30]] },
                            { name: 'Point27', id: 'Point27', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 31]] },
                            { name: 'Point28', id: 'Point28', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 32]] },
                            { name: 'Point29', id: 'Point29', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 33]] },
                            { name: 'Point30', id: 'Point30', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 34]] },
                            { name: 'Point31', id: 'Point31', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 35]] },
                            { name: 'Point32', id: 'Point32', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 36]] },
                            { name: 'Point33', id: 'Point33', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 37]] },
                            { name: 'Point34', id: 'Point34', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 38]] },
                            { name: 'Point35', id: 'Point35', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 39]] },
                            { name: 'Point36', id: 'Point36', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 40]] },
                            { name: 'Point37', id: 'Point37', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 41]] },
                            { name: 'Point38', id: 'Point38', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 42]] },
                            { name: 'Point39', id: 'Point39', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 43]] },
                            { name: 'Point40', id: 'Point40', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 44]] },
                            { name: 'Point41', id: 'Point41', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 45]] },
                            { name: 'Point42', id: 'Point42', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 46]] },
                            { name: 'Point43', id: 'Point43', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 47]] },
                            { name: 'Point44', id: 'Point44', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 48]] },
                            { name: 'Point45', id: 'Point45', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 49]] },
                            { name: 'Point46', id: 'Point46', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 50]] },
                            { name: 'Point47', id: 'Point47', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 51]] },
                            { name: 'Point48', id: 'Point48', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 52]] },
                            { name: 'Point49', id: 'Point49', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 53]] },
                            { name: 'Point50', id: 'Point50', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 54]] },
                            { name: 'Point51', id: 'Point51', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 55]] },
                            { name: 'Point52', id: 'Point52', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 56]] },
                            { name: 'Point53', id: 'Point53', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 57]] },
                            { name: 'Point54', id: 'Point54', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 58]] },
                            { name: 'Point55', id: 'Point55', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 59]] },
                            { name: 'Point56', id: 'Point56', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 60]] },
                            { name: 'Point57', id: 'Point57', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 61]] },
                            { name: 'Point58', id: 'Point58', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 62]] },
                            { name: 'Point59', id: 'Point59', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 63]] },
                            { name: 'Point60', id: 'Point60', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 64]] },
                            { name: 'Point61', id: 'Point61', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 65]] },
                            { name: 'Point62', id: 'Point62', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 66]] },
                            { name: 'Point63', id: 'Point63', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 67]] },
                            { name: 'Point64', id: 'Point64', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 68]] },
                            { name: 'Point65', id: 'Point65', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 69]] },
                            { name: 'Point66', id: 'Point66', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 70]] },
                            { name: 'Point67', id: 'Point67', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 71]] },
                            { name: 'Point68', id: 'Point68', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 72]] },
                            { name: 'Point69', id: 'Point69', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 73]] },
                            { name: 'Point70', id: 'Point70', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 74]] },
                            { name: 'Point71', id: 'Point71', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 75]] },
                            { name: 'Point72', id: 'Point72', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 76]] },
                            { name: 'Point73', id: 'Point73', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 77]] },
                            { name: 'Point74', id: 'Point74', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 78]] },
                            { name: 'Point75', id: 'Point75', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 79]] },
                            { name: 'Point76', id: 'Point76', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 80]] },
                            { name: 'Point77', id: 'Point77', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 81]] },
                            { name: 'Point78', id: 'Point78', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 82]] },
                            { name: 'Point79', id: 'Point79', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 83]] },
                            { name: 'Point80', id: 'Point80', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 84]] },
                            { name: 'Point81', id: 'Point81', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 85]] },
                            { name: 'Point82', id: 'Point82', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 86]] },
                            { name: 'Point83', id: 'Point83', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 87]] },
                            { name: 'Point84', id: 'Point84', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 88]] },
                            { name: 'Point85', id: 'Point85', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 89]] },
                            { name: 'Point86', id: 'Point86', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 90]] },
                            { name: 'Point87', id: 'Point87', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 91]] },
                            { name: 'Point88', id: 'Point88', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 92]] },
                            { name: 'Point89', id: 'Point89', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 93]] },
                            { name: 'Point90', id: 'Point90', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 94]] },
                            { name: 'Point91', id: 'Point91', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 95]] },
                            { name: 'Point92', id: 'Point92', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 96]] },
                            { name: 'Point93', id: 'Point93', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 97]] },
                            { name: 'Point94', id: 'Point94', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 98]] },
                            { name: 'Point95', id: 'Point95', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 99]] },
                            { name: 'Point96', id: 'Point96', data: [ ['v1', 1], ['v2', 2], ['v3', 3], ['v4', 4], ['v5', 100]] }
                            ]
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using set **`cropTreshold`**

```
 series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            turboThreshold: 0,
            cropThreshold: 500,
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/rofyy9th/3/)**

Comment: @Sajeeetharan Thanks a lot! Worked for me.